# RSpec Mocking system calls intermittently results in $?.exitstatus 127 on Jenkins CI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec, jenkins, exit-code

We are using the mock out method for making system calls:

```
before do
  subject.stub(:`) { `(exit 0)` }
end
...
#when running the tests we check the result of the last shell command using $?

if $?.exitstatus == 0
  # some code
end
```

This works locally using jruby 1.7.9 on mac osx. But when the builders execute these same tests using jenkins CI we have an intermittent result of `$?.exitstatus == 127`. Since the stub points off to a subshell that should only return exit code 0 this is extremely bizarre.

My questions are: 
**What are the possible causes of this discrepancy?** 
**Is there some difference between the linux variable `$?` and the ruby call to `$?.exitstatus` that could lead to getting inconsistent results?**

We have since worked around the issue by implementing a stub on how we retrieve `exitstatus` so this is more a question to satisfy my curiosity.